# Relación uno a muchos en diseño de base de datos relacionales

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, modelorelacional

Hola tengo una duda respecto a la llave foránea en un relacion de uno a muchos.
He leido que la llave foránea siempre va en la tabla que hace referencia a "muchos".
¿Esto siempre se cumple? y si no es asi ¿En qué casos no se cumpliría?

Answer (score 1):

si, siempre debería cumplirse y el razonamiento es bastante sencillo. En una relación de 1 a muchos la clave del 1 se propaga a muchos, ya que si fuera de muchos a 1 ocurriría un atributo multivaluado y esto rompería las formas normales del modelo relacional. En caso de una base de datos no relacional no sabría decirte, espero haberte ayudado.